# Stop Embedded Google Form From Forwarding To Success Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom setup for a contact form that calls to a Google form, when the form is submitted on my website, the user will be directed to the "Thank you..." page.

Is there a way I can prevent this?
I want to just have the form become invisible, and have a custom thank you note on the website.

from what I've found, there doesn't seem to be a "target='_blank'" kind of thing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add a hidden iframe to the page with a `name=hide` attrib, then on the form tag, add `target=hide` attrib. do note that an error page/message would also be hidden, not just the success message.